# "pager: true" vs "pager: #someid" in jqGrid, how to use them properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am playing a little bit with the jqGrid setup and some things aren't clear to me like the proper usage of `pager`. The idea is to add some custom buttons to the `top` and `bottom` bars.

This is the code I have been playing with:

```
$("#order_logs").jqGrid({
    url: 'api_order_logs',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: $('#colmodel').data('values'),
    width: 980,
    height: 300,
    pager: true,
    toppager: true,
    hoverrows: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100],
    data: [],
    rownumWidth: 100,
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    gridview: true,
    sortable: {
        options: {
            items: ">th:not(:has(#jqgh_grid_cb,#jqgh_grid_rn,#jqgh_grid_actions),:hidden)"
        }
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'rows',
        page: 'page',
        total: 'total',
        records: 'records',
        cell: '',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    cmTemplate: {autoResizable: true, editable: true},
    autoResizing: {compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true},
    autoresizeOnLoad: true,
    forceClientSorting: true
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refresh: true,
    refreshstate: "current",
    cloneToTop: true
}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#gridpager', {
    caption: 'Export',
    title: 'Export',
    buttonicon: 'fa fa-download',
    onClickButton: function () {
        // @todo
    }
}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#gridpager', {
    caption: 'Email',
    title: 'Email',
    buttonicon: 'fa fa-envelope-o',
    onClickButton: function () {
        // @todo
    }
}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#gridpager', {
    caption: 'Print',
    title: 'Print',
    buttonicon: 'fa fa-print',
    onClickButton: function () {
        // @todo
    }
});
```

With the usage of `pager: true` the grid display as follow:

[image: selection_002]

Meaning no custom buttons at top nor bottom.

With the usage of `pager: #gridpager` the grid display as follow:

[image: selection_001]

Meaning only custom buttons on the bottom bar but not on the top one.

Certainly I am missing something but I can't find what that is. I've been checking some docs [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/), [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/) and last [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) but still not clear to me how to deal with this in the right way.

In addition to this if you notice I am trying to use the fontAwesome iconset but images are missing, should I add the CSS file on my templates?

PS: I am using the latest version of jqGrid-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. Which sense is repeating the same value `'#gridpager'` as jqGrid option, as the parameter of `navGrid` and `navButtonAdd`?

jqGrid can contain maximal two pagers: bottom pager and top pager. The top pager can be created by usage of the option `toppager: true`. You don't use the option `toppager: true`. Then **the only** legal value of the first parameter of `navGrid` and `navButtonAdd` will be `'#gridpager'`. Correct?

Now, one can use `getGridParam` method to get any option of jqGrid after the grid is created. For example one can get the value of `pager` parameter using

```
var pagerIdSelector = $("#order_logs").jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager");
```

Free jqGrid allows to use

```
}).jqGrid('navGrid',  { ... });
```

instead of

```
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', { ... });
```

It tests the type of the first parameter. If the type of the first parameter isn't `"string"` then it uses `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager")` to get the value.

Now we can remind about the possibility to use `toppager: true` to create top pager. In the case **jqGrid creates** an empty `<div>` for the top pager, it generates, it assigns unique `id` for the `<div>`. Finally jqGrid changes the value of `toppager` parameter from `true` to the value like `#order_logs_toppager`, there the first part of the id (`order_logs`) is the id of the grid. Free jqGrid allows to use `true` as the value of `pager` parameter. In the case one can simplify the HTML and remove unneeded empty div

```
<div id="gridpager"><div>
```

If one uses **both** `pager: true` and `toppager: true` options and uses `navGrid` or `navButtonAdd` **without** pager parameters then jqGrid places the buttons on **both** pagers. If you need to place some buttons only on one pager then you can use the code like below. If place some buttons on both pagers and then place another buttons on specific pagers:

```
var $grid = $("#order_logs");

$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    pager: true,
    toppager: true,
    ...
});

// create nav bar and place Refresh button on both pagers
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refreshstate: "current",
});

var bottomPagerIdSelector = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager"),
    topPagerIdSelector = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "toppager");
// place Export button only on bottom pager
// and Email button only on top pager
$grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', bottomPagerIdSelector, {
    caption: 'Export',
    title: 'Export',
    buttonicon: 'fa fa-download',
    onClickButton: function () {
        // @todo
    }
}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', topPagerIdSelector, {
    caption: 'Email',
    title: 'Email',
    buttonicon: 'fa fa-envelope-o',
    onClickButton: function () {
        // @todo
    }
});
```

The final remarks. You use `forceClientSorting: true` option, which works only in combination with `loadonce: true`. jqGrid can sort all the data only it it has all data.

The value of `sortable` parameter is wrong. The selectors like `jqgh_grid_cb` contains `"grid"` in the middle, which should be the id of the grid. In your case it could be `"order_logs"` instead of `"grid"` (`jqgh_grid_cb` shoule be replaced to `jqgh_order_logs_cb`).

Comment: This is a great answer however I am missing this "In addition to this if you notice I am trying to use the fontAwesome 5 (can I use such version??) iconset but images are missing, should I add the CSS file on my templates?" what would be the answer for this?

Comment: @ReynierPM: I don't use Font Awesome 5 myself and don't know whether the names of classes of icons in Font Awesome 5 are different to the corresponding classes names of Font Awesome 4. Do you have any compatibility problems? In general one should post always separate questions and never post communicative questions. Separate questions can be easy indexed and found by other visitors.

Comment: And that is my bad, I was referring to FA4, 5 does not exists. I'll fix the OP

Comment: @ReynierPM: Font Awesome 5 does exist, but it's commercial and I didn't bought it for me.

Comment: @ReynierPM: Do you added something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` on your page? See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data) an example of usage Font Awesome.

Comment: Nope, I didn't that was my doubt if I depend on the library or was built in, now I know I depend on the external file, thanks