# Why "allData" is an empty array?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to get the data from a jqGrid (free version and latest version) and it's suppose that I get:

- all the data if none is selected
- the selected data if any

This is how I am doing it:

```
$(function () {
    var $order_logs = $('#order_logs');
    $order_logs.jqGrid({
        url: Routing.generate('api_order_logs'),
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: $colmodel.data('values'),
        width: 980,
        height: 300,
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        rowList: [25, 50, 100],
        rownumWidth: 60,
        gridview: true,
        sortable: {
            options: {
                items: ">th:not(:has(#jqgh_order_logs_cb,#jqgh_order_logs_rn,#jqgh_order_logs_actions),:hidden)"
            }
        },
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'rows',
            page: 'page',
            total: 'total',
            records: 'records',
            cell: '',
            repeatitems: false
        },
        cmTemplate: {autoResizable: true, editable: true},
        autoResizing: {compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true},
        autoresizeOnLoad: true
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        refresh: true,
        refreshstate: "current",
        cloneToTop: true
    }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', {
        caption: 'Export',
        title: 'Export',
        onClickButton: function () {
            var filteredData = $order_logs.jqGrid("getGridParam").lastSelectedData,
                allData = $order_logs.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

            exportData(filteredData, allData);
        }
    });
});

function exportData(filteredData, allData) {
    if (filteredData.length === 0 || allData.length === 0) {
        alert('There is no data to export');
        return;
    }

    // Export only the filtered data
    if (filteredData.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Export all the grid data
}
```

For some reason the value of `allData` is always an empty array and I am not sure since I am using the same code as everyone is using out there and found in a lot of answer here in SO.

**UPDATE**:

Currently the grid is holding six columns and a set of 60 records as total paginated by 20 each time however you can change the pagination to be 50 or 100.

Can any tell me why is this?

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? If the `datatype` isn't local, then another question: do you use `loadonce: true` option? jqGrid can return all local data only if it has the local data. In the same way `lastSelectedData` exist only if the data are sorted and filtered *locally*. **How many total rows and columns are in the dataset, which you try to display?** In case of about <10000 you can use `loadonce: true` and have good performance.

Comment: @Oleg the grid JS is exactly the same as in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302506/pager-true-vs-pager-someid-in-jqgrid-how-to-use-them-properly) with the exception that I've removed the `loadonce: true` option

Comment: If you don't have local data in the grid and fill only one page of data, then you can't get all the data from jqGrid. I asked you (see bold text) how many rows (on all pages) and columns are in jqGrid. Could you answer on the question? Is `loadonce: true` an option for you? Without holding and filtering the data locally jqGrid can't help you to return the data.

Comment: @Oleg I've updated the OP with some extra info and yes `loadonce: true` could be an option. This data is coming from MongoDB so it's not a big deal.

Comment: I posted my answer and I recommend you to try to use filter toolbar of the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ and https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/. The content for the filtering of Client, Tax and Shipped Via columns will be build by free jqGrid just by adding corresponding options. The demo is a little too long because I tried to demonstrates different possibilities in one demo. I think such features could be interesting and all there are possible only with local data: after adding `loadonce: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options in case of small dataset: less at 1000 or 10000 rows. It simplifies the code server side and you can use full functionality of free jqGrid. The problem with access to `lastSelectedData` and `data` will be solved.

More then that, you can easy use many advanced features like `createColumnIndex: true`, `generateValue: true` of `generateDatalist: true` options and so on. See demos included in [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.14.1.md#new-main-features-implemented-in-the-version-4141-compared-with-4140) of version 4.14.1. Good and comfortable filtering of the data is, in my option, the part of displaying the data. Having the data locally allows to find unique values and build `<select>` in the filter bar or to use `<datalist>` to have autocomplete functionality.

Comment: OK, I will explore both of them but so far it could be the case where I have more than 10 thousand records which as you mention could be an issue. One question/doubt I do have is how do I know if the grid hasn't any data at all? I want to prevent an AJAX call to be made if the grid hasn't any data at all so there is nothing to export.

Comment: @ReynierPM: jqGrid can't "know" how many data exist in the server side. Because of that it has to make Ajax request to get the data. If *you* knows that at the beginning there are no data then you can just use `datatype: "local"` without any `data`. It creates empty grid and `url` parameter will be ignored. You can later change the `datatype` to `"json"` and call `$order_logs.trigger("reloadGrid");` It will fill the data of the grid.

Comment: @ReynierPM: By the way, you can try the performance of paging, sorting and filtering of large local on the demos: [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-15-60000-25-free-jqgrid.htm), which uses 60000 rows, 15 columns and 25 rows per page and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) with 5000 instead of 60000 rows. I think that performance of the grid with 6 columns and 10 thousand records rows will be even better as the demo with 5000 rows and 13 columns.

Comment: can this be done by loading all of them at once from a remote source? Any example of this for see how it works and make some tests?

Comment: @ReynierPM: You need just use `url: "someUrl"`, which returns the same data in JSON format, `datatype: "json", loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true`. jqGrid will load the data and generate local `data` file based on `colModel` and optionally `additionalProperties`. Then the `data` will be sorted and filtered *locally* in absolutely the same way like in case of `datatype: "local"` with the `data` input. The first page of result will be displayed. The performance will be practically identical to my previous demos.

Comment: @ReynierPM: The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/h84jemsh/ is the copy of  the previous demo https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm, but using JSFiddle echo service.